# progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable() doesn't work

Tags: android

When I try change my indeteminateDrawable progressbar just gone( 
I have to change drawable for my progressbar. I tried invalidate, requestLayout and other. I dont know how I can fix it.
Thank you..............

**Here code:**

```
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.‌​progress_indeterminate_horizontal_didnt_like));

progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Yes. It's visible in XML.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
         android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_to_review" />
```

---

```
  private void showProgressByCategory(String category) {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);


        switch (CATEGORY.getPosition(category)) {
        case CATEGORY.DIDNT_LIKE_POS:
            // Didnt like
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal_didnt_like));

            break;
        case CATEGORY.TO_SEE_POS:
            // To See
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal_to_see));
            break;
        case CATEGORY.SAW_AND_LIKED_POS:
            // Saw And Liked
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal_saw_liked));
            break;
        case CATEGORY.TO_REVIEW_POS:
            // To Review
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal_to_review));

            break;
        }
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
```

Comment: progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal_didnt_like));

.
.
.
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

Comment: don't comment it, put it on your post by editing your post.

Comment: Is the progressbar visibility set? Post layout/code where you create the progressbar in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the same problem by creating a new ProgressBar whenever I want to change the Drawable.

Note:

1. Hide previous ProgressBar.
2. Create new one and show it.

Code:

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ResultType resultType;

    public enum ResultType {
        eNone,
        eSuccess,
        eFail;
    }

    public void hide(String message, long completionIndicatorInterval) {
        hide();

        if ( (completionIndicatorInterval > 0) &&
                (resultType != ResultType.eNone)) {
            final MyProgressDialog completedDialog = new MyProgressDialog(getContext());
            completedDialog.setCancelable(false);
            completedDialog.setMessage(message);

            if (resultType == ResultType.eSuccess) {
                Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check);
                completedDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
                completedDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            } else {
                Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close_image);
                completedDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
                completedDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            }

            completedDialog.show();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    hide();
                    completedDialog.hide();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, completionIndicatorInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you must call `drawable.setBounds()` with intrinsic size before `setIndeterminateDrawable()` to solve

Answer (score 3):

if your drawable is an animation (drawable with `animation-list`), you should call your drawable as `AnimationDrwable`. Set with `setIndeterminateDrawable` and call start for your drawable.

```
AnimationDrawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_custom_drawable);
    Rect bounds = progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().getBounds(); // get bounds from current drawable
    progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
    drawable.start();
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setBounds(bounds); //thanks ceabie
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the following:

```
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(yourDrawable)
progressBar.requestLayout();
```