# Android ProgressBar setIndeterminateDrawable()

Tags: android, android-widget, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I'm trying to change a progress bar's indeterminate drawable on an event. When calling

```
mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
```

The progress has no background. The drawable is valid and works if I set it in XML. Any idea's on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the ProgressBar source code, it looks like `setIndeterminateDrawable` doesn't call `updateDrawableBounds` so you'll have to manually set the bounds on your new drawable.

Comment: short example would be great.

Comment: I wasn't able to find out on which object I should call `updateDrawableBounds` so I placed new full answer with full example how to solve this issue. See below.

Answer (score 1):

After setting new drawable, we have to set its bounds.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_new_custom_drawable);
Rect bounds = progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().getBounds(); // re-use bounds from current drawable
progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable); // set new drawable
progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setBounds(bounds); // set bounds to new drawable
```

Answer (score -1):

After *setIndeterminateDrawable()* you must call *requestLayout()*

Ex:

```
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(yourDrawable)
progressBar.requestLayout();
```

The same question was answered here: 
[progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743559/progressbar-setindeterminatedrawable-doesnt-work)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on API 21 and API 22 devices and emulators